# Using unix join -o to not print the common field

Tags: unix, join

I am using 
`join -1 2 -2 2 file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt` to join my two text files based on their second column and write them to file3.txt, which works perfectly. However, I do not want file3.txt to contain the common field. Googling and join's `man` page suggests that the `-o` formatting operator could help accomplish this, but how exactly should I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each file only has two columns, and you want to join on the second column but show only the first columns of each file in your output, use

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1 file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Remember that your two files should be sorted on the second column before joining.

An example run:

```
$ cat file1.txt
2 1
3 2
7 2
8 4
2 6
$ cat file2.txt 
3 1
5 4
9 9
$ join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1 file1.txt file2.txt
2 3
8 5
```